# Efficiently listing all last-level descendants of each root in a proper hierarchical graph (bipartite DAG)

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis, graph-traversal

Let G = (V, E) be a graph which is hierarchical in the sense that its vertices are arranged in levels/layers (say 1 to k) and an edge can only be from a vertex at level i to a vertex at level i+1. Vertices at level 1 and k are called the *roots* and the *leaves*, respectively. The problem is to find all descendant leaves of each root.
For instance, for the following graph,
[image]

the answer would be:
1: 12, 13
2: 12, 13
3: 12, 13, 14, 15, 16
4: 14, 15, 16

A naive solution can be to run a DFS for each root which will take O(r(n+m)) time where r is #roots, n is #vertices and m is #edges.

Can we do better?
Another way to see the same graph is that it is a bipartite DAG.

Comment: Maybe the chain multiplication of the adjacency matrices between each two levels can be more efficient.

Comment: You basically want the transitive closure of this graph.  You could use fast matrix multiplication, as Willard Zhan says.  See also http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/553/5038, which is very closely related and describes papers in the literature that study this problem.

Comment: Transitive closure works for reachability in general graph. But in this particular case, simpler dynamic programming suffice. Imagine you can memo a set of reachable leaves at each vertex. The reachable leaves set of a vertex is the union of all the sets for each its child. Thus you can compute these set by propagating backwards.

Comment: Thanks WillardZhan and @D.W. , but wouldn't calculating transitive closure be O(n^w) and then finding the corresponding pairs (root, leaf)  be O(r * l) where r=#roots and l=#leaves. OTOH the DFS approach is O(r*n + r*m). As r < n, transitive closure will not always be a better option.

Comment: @RituKundu, yes, that looks right to me.

Comment: You could also just run through the intermediate nodes and delete them, replacing each node with parent -> child edges for each of its parents and children.  eg delete 8 above and create 5->12, 6->12, 5->13, 6->13 edges.  The number of edges created is somewhat bounded.

Comment: @Billiska Thanks. I was working on the union idea and about to post the same. Each edge corresponds to a union operation which will be L (=#leaves). In case of adjacency list representation, I will have to spend O(n+Lm). I pointer representation, it will be O(Lm). I was daunted by an extra piece of information, which I did not mention in the question, that m = cn for a constant c. So, effectively, DFS was O(rm). But I will probably combine the two solutions depending on L and r. Thanks, again.

Comment: @KWillets Thanks. It might provide a practical speed-up (although deletion will also have a cost depending on the representation). But I think it won't be able to improve the worst case time-complexity.

Comment: @Ritu The worst case is pretty bad, since you can get o(n^2) output pairs by eg making n/2 roots and n/2 leaves in a bipartite clique.

Answer (score 1):

Define $\ell(v)$ to be the leaves reachable from a node $v$. Note the following:

> **Lemma 1**: For all non-leaf nodes $v$ we have: $$\ell(v) = \cup_{u \in c(v)} \ell(u)$$ where $c(v)$ is the set of all children of $v$.

We now construct an algorithm around this:

1. Let $A = \{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$ be the *reverse* topological order of nodes in $G$.
2. For all $v \in A$:

   1. If $v$ is a leaf node, define $\ell(v) = \{v\}$.
   2. Otherwise, define $\ell(v)$ as we did in **Lemma 1**.

Now the complexity of this is $O(km + n)$ where $k$ is the average cost of union-ing the $\ell$-sets of the children of a non-leaf node. How you go about union-ing the sets is up to you. Standard merging is easy to implement. You could also try using a disjoint-set data structure, but this becomes tricky because a node might have multiple parents.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that takes advantage of [path compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Path_compression).

1. Let $\ell$ be the set of leaf nodes.
2. Let $G'$ be the same graph as $G$ except every edge is direction the opposite way.
3. For each $v \in \ell$ call $\mathrm{Find}(v)$ and store this as a reverse mapping from all $u \in \mathrm{Find}(v)$ to $v$.

Find with path compression must be implemented a bit differently because there are multiple parents:

```
Find(u):
  if u is a root node:
    return u
  if u is a child of only roots:
    return children of u
  else:
    roots = {}
    for each child v of u that's not a root in G':
      for each node x in Find(v):
        add x to roots
    delete all edges from v to a child u in G'
    for each node x in roots:
      add an edge from u to x in G'
```

Here is how it would work on your example.

#### Step 1:

[image: step1]

#### Step 2: Find(12)

[image: step2]

#### Step 3: Find(13)

[image: step3]

#### Step 4, 5, and 6: Find(14), Find(15), Find(16)

[image: step456]

Analysis of this is rather tricky because there is a cost for adding all the edges, but a benefit for shortening the distance between a leaf and its root(s). The edges can end up growing quadratically, but then again this will only be the case if the output will end up being quadratic.